# HTTP request response does not show in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, google-chrome-extension

I make a request from my Chrome extension to my server.

Yesterday everything worked well, but today the answer to the request is not displayed in Chrome, i.e. it is not displayed on the Network tab. I have recorded netlog, but I can not understand what the problem is.

```
129868: URL_REQUEST
https://maa.com:444/login
Start Time: 2019-03-26 19:06:58.027

t=60785 [st=  0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=187]
                  --> priority = "MEDIUM"
                  --> url = "https://maa.com:444/login"
t=60785 [st=  0]    NETWORK_DELEGATE_BEFORE_URL_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=60785 [st=  0]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=186]
                    --> load_flags = 832 (DO_NOT_SAVE_COOKIES | DO_NOT_SEND_AUTH_DATA | DO_NOT_SEND_COOKIES)
                    --> method = "POST"
                    --> privacy_mode = 1
                    --> upload_id = "0"
                    --> url = "https://maa.com:444/login"
t=60785 [st=  0]      NETWORK_DELEGATE_BEFORE_START_TRANSACTION  [dt=0]
t=60785 [st=  0]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=60785 [st=  0]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=60785 [st=  0]        HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_BOUND
                        --> source_dependency = 129869 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER)
t=60785 [st=  0]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                        --> source_dependency = 129870 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=60785 [st=  0]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=60785 [st=  0]      UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_INIT  [dt=0]
                      --> is_chunked = false
                      --> net_error = 0 (?)
                      --> total_size = 256
t=60785 [st=  0]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=60785 [st=  0]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                        --> POST /login HTTP/1.1
                            Host: maa.com:444
                            Connection: keep-alive
                            Content-Length: 256
                            Origin: chrome-extension://lhdgaofngmjabfvbejndlafpkbiofjga
                            User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36
                            Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryAIiqVCANUCfdRMIy
                            Accept: */*
                            Referer: https://maa.date/
                            Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
                            Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5
t=60785 [st=  0]        UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                        --> current_position = 0
t=60785 [st=  0]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_BODY
                        --> did_merge = true
                        --> is_chunked = false
                        --> length = 256
t=60785 [st=  0]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=60785 [st=  0]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=186]
t=60785 [st=  0]        HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=185]
t=60971 [st=186]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS
                        --> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                            Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
                            Date: Tue, 26 Mar 2019 16:06:59 GMT
                            Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
                            Transfer-Encoding: chunked
                            Connection: keep-alive
                            Vary: Accept-Encoding
                            Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpXYZiOjE1NTM2MTY0MTksImV4cCI6MTU1MzYxNzAxOSwidXNlcklkIjoyLCJ0b2tlbiI6IjQ3MDgxOGM1LWI3MWEtNDEwMi1iYWVkLWVjYTA1M2EwMjM3MSJ9.zZb3v6-mb_HuV7tXuaIpJ5GdeXLV2ML_k-C8sK9E28E
                            Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
                            Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
                            Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
                            Access-Control-Allow-Origin: chrome-extension://lhdgaofngmjabfvbejndlafpkbiofjga
                            Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
                            Content-Encoding: gzip
t=60971 [st=186]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS
t=60971 [st=186]      NETWORK_DELEGATE_HEADERS_RECEIVED  [dt=0]
t=60971 [st=186]      URL_REQUEST_FILTERS_SET
                      --> filters = "GZIP"
t=60971 [st=186]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
t=60971 [st=186]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE_RESPONSE_STARTED  [dt=0]
t=60971 [st=186]    HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=0]
t=60971 [st=186]    URL_REQUEST_JOB_BYTES_READ
                    --> byte_count = 104
t=60971 [st=186]    URL_REQUEST_JOB_FILTERED_BYTES_READ
                    --> byte_count = 95
t=60972 [st=187]    CANCELLED
t=60972 [st=187] -REQUEST_ALIVE



129869: HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER
https://maa.com:444/login
Start Time: 2019-03-26 19:06:58.027

t=60785 [st=0] +HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER  [dt=0]
                --> is_preconnect = false
                --> url = "https://maa.com:444/login"
t=60785 [st=0]    HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_BOUND
                  --> source_dependency = 129868 (URL_REQUEST)
t=60785 [st=0]   +PROXY_RESOLUTION_SERVICE  [dt=0]
t=60785 [st=0]      PROXY_RESOLUTION_SERVICE_RESOLVED_PROXY_LIST
                    --> pac_string = "DIRECT"
t=60785 [st=0]   -PROXY_RESOLUTION_SERVICE
t=60785 [st=0]    HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_PROXY_SERVER_RESOLVED
                  --> proxy_server = "DIRECT"
t=60785 [st=0]    HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_STARTED_JOB
                  --> source_dependency = 129870 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=60785 [st=0] -HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER



129870: HTTP_STREAM_JOB
https://maa.com:444/
Start Time: 2019-03-26 19:06:58.027

t=60785 [st=0] +HTTP_STREAM_JOB  [dt=0]
                --> expect_spdy = false
                --> original_url = "https://maa.com:444/"
                --> priority = "MEDIUM"
                --> source_dependency = 129869 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER)
                --> url = "https://maa.com:444/"
                --> using_quic = false
t=60785 [st=0]    HTTP_STREAM_JOB_WAITING  [dt=0]
                  --> should_wait = false
t=60785 [st=0]   +HTTP_STREAM_JOB_INIT_CONNECTION  [dt=0]
t=60785 [st=0]     +HOST_RESOLVER_IMPL_REQUEST  [dt=0]
                    --> address_family = 0
                    --> allow_cached_response = true
                    --> host = "maa.com:444"
                    --> is_speculative = false
t=60785 [st=0]        HOST_RESOLVER_IMPL_IPV6_REACHABILITY_CHECK
                      --> cached = true
                      --> ipv6_available = false
t=60785 [st=0]        HOST_RESOLVER_IMPL_CACHE_HIT
                      --> addresses = ["95.216.161.231"]
                      --> expiration = "13198090077767621"
t=60785 [st=0]     -HOST_RESOLVER_IMPL_REQUEST
t=60785 [st=0]     +SOCKET_POOL  [dt=0]
t=60785 [st=0]        SOCKET_POOL_REUSED_AN_EXISTING_SOCKET
                      --> idle_ms = 3
t=60785 [st=0]        SOCKET_POOL_BOUND_TO_SOCKET
                      --> source_dependency = 129866 (SOCKET)
t=60785 [st=0]     -SOCKET_POOL
t=60785 [st=0]   -HTTP_STREAM_JOB_INIT_CONNECTION
t=60785 [st=0]    HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_PROTO
                  --> proto = "http/1.1"
t=60785 [st=0]    HTTP_STREAM_JOB_BOUND_TO_REQUEST
                  --> source_dependency = 129868 (URL_REQUEST)
t=60785 [st=0] -HTTP_STREAM_JOB
```

Is there something weird in my log? I will be glad to any advice on this situation.

Comment: It could be a bug in Chrome or maybe something else is interfering. Try reproducing the problem in another browser, in an older portable Chrome, in Chrome Canary, in a new browser profile, and so on.

Comment: @wOxxOm Did it in few other browsers, same results.

Answer (score 0):

It was a CORB issue (or bug).

Added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` (previously value was taken from request `Origin` header) to my server response headers and everything works just fine.

[Cross-Origin Read Blocking for Web Developers](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers)